# Insert struct have array to Mongodb with Go

Tags: go, mgo

I want to insert datastruct like below to MongoDB

`{
    "rolecode": "DHBK1_ROLE_04",
    "functioncodelist": [
        "DHBK1_FUNC_1",
        "DHBK1_FUNC_2",
          .....
        "DHBK1_FUNC_n"]
    "productid": "ABC_Platform",
    "comid": "DHBK1"
}`

Here is my code:

```
package main
import (
    "context"
    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2"
)


func main() {
    insertObj()
}
type CompanyRoleFunction struct {
    Rolecode         string `json:"rolecode"`
    Productid        string `json:"productid"`
    Functioncodelist []string
    Comid string `json:"comid"`
}
func insertObj() {
    session, err := mgo.Dial("mongodb://casuser:Mellon@222.255.102.145:27017/users")
    if err != nil {
    panic(err)
    }
    c := session.DB("users").C("company_role_function")
    var companyRoleFunction CompanyRoleFunction
    companyRoleFunction.Rolecode = "DHBK1_ROLE_05"
    companyRoleFunction.Productid = "XYZ_Platform"
    companyRoleFunction.Comid = "DHBK1"
    err = c.Insert(companyRoleFunction)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}
```

My code have run but it only insert struct like this (of course, because I don't know how to handle array Functioncodelist )

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Here is my data, I hope to insert

`{"_id":{"$oid":"5ed0c2e2402a000037004c84"},"rolecode":"DHBK1_ROLE_07","functioncodelist":["DHBK1_FUNC_1","DHBK1_FUNC_2"],"productid":"ABC_Platform","comid":"DHBK1"}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't show up in the database because the document you inserted did not contain any values.
Set a value in your go code and it should show up just fine in the database, unless I misinterpreted your question.

```
...
type Functioncode string
...
companyRoleFunction.Functioncodelist = make(map[string]Functioncode)
...
companyRoleFunction.Functioncodelist["foo"] = "bar"
...
```

See https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/19 for a quick introduction to go maps.

Comment: I add your code but it show error ".\main.go:61:46: cannot use "bar" (type string) as type Functioncode in assignment". I have add database in my question. Please help me

Comment: In your code, Functioncode is an empty struct. Define Functioncode as something sensible that fulfills your needs and set the value accordingly. As far as I can see replacing Functioncode with just string would work fine.

Comment: Hi, I have edited my code, I chage functioncodelist to array, I think it will easy. Please help me. Thanks

Comment: We're not here to write your code for you. If you want to code in Go, you should at least read and understand the basic tutorials.